# Big Bug from Peru

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I'd like to have a name for this guy.  There were 5 or 6 of them zipping around the flower bed on the coast of Peru about 120 kms south of Lima.[image]

Comment: Nice photo! :) :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That is a hawkmoth, probably *Hyles annei* (Guerin-Meneville, 1839). It is one of a number of moth species commonly called "hummingbird," "sphinx," or "hawk" moths in the family Sphingidae.

Beautiful, isn't it? :)

edit - sorry, I originally misidentified this as Hyles lineata - the pattern is slightly different.

Comment: Image search on "hawkmoth" turns up some stellar photos. Here is a [close-up of an eye](http://www-tc.pbs.org/wnet/nature/files/2015/08/HUMMINGBIRD-HAWKMOTH-EYE-1280x854.jpg).

Comment: @DavidS That is amazing.